# $w_1, \dots , w_n \in W$ are linearly independent, prove that so also $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$, if $f(v_i) = w_i$

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. If $w_1, \dots , w_n \in W$ are linearly independent, prove that so also $v_1, ..., v_n \in V$, if $f(v_i) = w_i$, for $i = 1,\dots,n$.

I have tried to figure this out, but the problem is that I don't know the definition of $f$, so maybe it could make vectors that are linearly dependent $v_i$ to vectors that are linearly independent $w_i$.

Comment: It would be standard usage to say "for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ or to say "for $i=1,\ldots,n$".  But "for all $i=1,\ldots,n$" exposes its writer as one writing in a foreign language.  I don't recall ever seeing it done by a mathematician.

Comment: I already changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Outline: suppose as usual you have scalars $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ such that 
$$
0_V = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k v_k.
$$
The goal is to prove that one must have $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n = 0$. To do so, apply $f$ to both sides:
$$
0_W=f(0_V)= f\left( \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k v_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k f(v_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k w_k
$$
where we used the fact that $f$ was a linear map to "take out" the sum and the scalars. Knowing that the $w_k$ *are* independent, can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Prove the contrapositive: If the $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly dependent, then so are the $w_1,\ldots,w_n$.

So assume

$$a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n=0$$

Then

$$a_1w_1+\ldots+a_nw_n=a_1f(v_1)+\ldots+a_nf(v_n)$$
$$=f(a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n)$$
$$=f(0)=0$$

Two steps there depend on the linearity of $f$.

Comment: It can be a direct proof as well.

Comment: @Bernard: Perhaps, but the proof of the contrapositive is short and clear. Note that both the answers given so far use the contrapositive (mine and Clement C.'s).

Comment: @RoryDaulton: it looks to me my argument is *not* by contrapositive: I assume the $w_j$'s are independent, and show then that any linear combination cancelling the $v_j$'s must be the trivial one, i.e. that the $v_j$'s are independent.

Comment: @ClementC.: You are right. I stand corrected. I still think my proof is short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a linear combination

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i v_i=0$$

Apply $f$ to this equality

$$\sum_{I=1}^n\lambda_i f(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i w_i=0$$

The $(w_i)_i$ being independent allows to conclude $\forall i\,\lambda_i=0$ and therefore the $(v_i)_i$ are linearly independent